# Why do pdf parsing libraries pdf2json and pdf-parse seem to not work with Next JS app router?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, pdfparser, pdf2json

I've been trying to implement pdf parsing logic in my Next JS app. It seems the libraries pdf2json and pdf-parse don't work with the new Next JS app router.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run `npx create-next-app@latest` and follow the prompts, and say Yes to using app router.
2. Add an API route under app/api/test

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import fs from "fs";
import PDFParser from "pdf2json";
import pdf from "pdf-parse";

export async function GET() {
   const pdfParser = new PDFParser();

   pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", (errData: any) =>
     console.error(errData.parserError)
   );
   pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", (pdfData: any) => {
     console.log(pdfData);
   });

   pdfParser.loadPDF("./sample.pdf");
  return NextResponse.json({});
}
```

3. Add a sample.pdf file in the root dir
4. Run from terminal `curl localhost:3000/api/test`, pdf2json throws an uncaught error:

```
- error node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js (66:0) @ eval
- error Error [ReferenceError]: nodeUtil is not defined
```

5. Trying pdf-parse returns a 404 not found for the API route

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import fs from "fs";
import PDFParser from "pdf2json";
import pdf from "pdf-parse";

export async function GET() {
   let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync("./sample.pdf");

  pdf(dataBuffer).then(function (data) {
    // number of pages
    console.log(data.numpages);
    // number of rendered pages
    console.log(data.numrender);
    // PDF info
    console.log(data.info);
    // PDF metadata
    console.log(data.metadata);
    // PDF.js version
    // check https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/
    console.log(data.version);
    // PDF text
    console.log(data.text);
  });
  return NextResponse.json({});
}
```

After creating a separate project with the old pages router in Next JS, none of the above issues occurred and it was able to parse the PDF properly.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: I'm getting the same "nodeUtil is not defined" with pdf2json in an Electron app.

Answer (score 5):

You need to update `next.config.js` file.

```html
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["pdf-parse"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

you need to add a folder test/data/05-versions-space.pdf

I know this is extremely random but if you look into the code you will see that it needs this file - can be any pdf - the path and name have to be the same.

[image: Filestructure]

Answer (score 0):

##### Here is how I fixed it

###### Step 1:

```
npm i patch-package
```

###### step 2:

```
npm i pdf-parse
```

###### step 3:

Go to this file : node_modules\pdf-parse\index.js

###### step 4:

Change this line

```
let isDebugMode = !module.parent; (for me is line 6)
```

to this one

```
let isDebugMode = false//!module.parent;
```

Just convert the isDebugMode to false. (I assume you understand what this will do if you read the code)

###### step 5:

run this command

```
npx patch-package pdf-parse
```

###### step 6:

go to the package.json and add this postinstall script

```json
"scripts": {
//your other scripts  

"postinstall": "patch-package" 
}
```

###### step 7:

delete this folder

.next\cache

###### step 8:

Go to your vercel deployment and redeploy without using the existing build cache (!important).
this ☝☝☝☝

Note:

if it does not work (not likely)

delete the package-lock.json and run

```
npm install
```

(am not sure if deleting package-lock.json is risky).

Let me know if it works for you